# C CreateFileMapping error 5 Access Denied ALWAYS

Tags: winapi

I would like to ask for help with WINAPI function CreateFileMapping (), which returns constantly NULL. After GetLastError() I get 5 - "ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED 5 (0x5) Access is denied". The file has been created after CreateFile with no problem, but following CreateFileMapping never has bee succesful.

```
int MapDestFile(LPCWSTR fPath)
{
hDestFile = CreateFile(
    fPath,
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);
if (hSourceFile == NULL)
{
    printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
}

hDestMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
    hDestFile,
    NULL,
    PAGE_READWRITE,
    0,  
    10,
    NULL
    );
if (hDestMapFile == NULL)
{
    // here always tell error number 5
    printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
}
lpMapAddressDestFile = MapViewOfFile(
    hDestMapFile,
    FILE_MAP_WRITE,
    0,
    0,
    0);

if (lpMapAddressDestFile == NULL)
{
    printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
}

return 1;
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create the file with `GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ` to match `PAGE_READWRITE`.

That seems self-evident when you think about it. How can you have memory that you can read from backed by a file that you cannot read from? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx) does call this out explicitly in any case:

> **PAGE_READWRITE**
>
> The file handle that the hFile parameter specifies must be created with the GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_WRITE access rights.

On top of that your error checking on the call to `CreateFile` is wrong. Take another look at the documentations. Error is indicated by a return value of `INVALID_FILE_HANDLE`.

Comment: Thanks. But with INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE the same situation. CreatFile(...) is OK, I see the file in file browser. The HANDLE is VALID, but CreatingFileMapping failed. Important thing I didn't mentioned is, that I need write to the file, so GENERIC_READ should not be suitable for me. Also I'm running Win7 (maybe this information have some value).

Comment: I think you need to read the answer again. I've expanded it, and re-ordered it. Read the first sentence. The think with `GENERIC_WRITE` and `GENERIC_READ` is that they are not either or. You need them **both**. Use bitwise or, as per my answer, to specify that.